# Is it OK to Change System Locale after MSSQL2012 installation

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have a MS SQL Server 2012 instance preinstalled on a Windows 2012 R2 production server. The Windows locale was English(EN-US), and SQL Server Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. The system handles all Chinese data with nvarchar fields just fine.

Later for some reason (unrelated to sql server) I may have to change default system locale of the Windows 2012 R2 server to Chinese. Will this cause any undesired side effect on the SQL server instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you *should* be ok. The only area that I am aware of that could be affected is SQLCLR, in which case the following conditions must be true:

1. (
   The LCID of the OS does not match the LCID of the default Collation of the Database where the Assembly is loaded,

   *OR*
2. The default Collation of the Database where the Assembly is loaded is either a binary Collation, or is *any* combination of the following: case-sensitive, accent-insensitive, width-sensitive, or Kana-type-sensitive
   ),

   AND
3. custom SQLCLR code is being used
4. `SqlString` is being used as an input parameter type
5. The `SqlString` parameter is being concatenated inline with a `string` while not using either the `Value` property or the `ToString()` method (i.e. `"some string" + SqlStringInputParam;`)
6. Or, *possibly* using Regular Expressions / `Regex`.

To be clear, this issue relates to the default Collation of the Database in which the Assembly is loaded, *not* the Instance- / Server- level Collation, nor even the Collation of any string column or any string literal or variable with a Collation set via the `COLLATE` keyword.

If your Database has a default Collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` because that is what the Instance-level Collation is, then neither # 1 nor # 2 above are true. And in that case, IF there is any SQLCLR code in that Database that matches items 4 - 6 above, then you wouldn't see any problem. BUT, changing the Locale of the OS would make item # 1 above true, in which case if there is any SQLCLR code that matches item 4 - 6 above, then that code will start to throw "Collation mismatch" exceptions.

Admittedly there is a fairly low probability of running into this. But, it has happened, so it's best to be aware of it.

Comment: Thank you. Its very informative. I did have a string aggr CLR addon, some code depend on it. I have change them to stuff, and dropped the CLR before changing over the locale. I don't seem to have any trouble so far.

Comment: @Ben Yer welcome. To be clear, I wasn't saying that _all_ SQLCLR was bad, or even all SQLCLR that uses `SqlString` is bad, just that it is something to be aware of, especially when the best practices of using the `Value` property or using the `ToString()` method were not being followed.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen to your SQL Server installation if you change the Windows system locale, because it was installed with the specific collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.